# Are there exegetical differences between "God and the Father" and "God the Father"?

Tags: galatians, colossians

Colossians 3:17 (DRB):

> ... God and the Father...

Colossians 2:2 (DRB):

> ... God the Father...

Galatians 1:4 (DRB):

> ... God and our Father...

Colossians 1:3 (DRB):

> ... God our Father...

Are there exegetical differences between "God and the Father" and "God the Father"?

Also, are there exegetical differences between "God and our Father" and "God our Father"?

God and the Father, means two different entities. Since there's no definite article before πατρι in the Greek text, so I think it should be "**the god and father**" not "**God and the Father**".I hope you understand me.

Comment: See my comment on your other [question](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/45396); the same principle applies here as well.

Comment: The Greek original of the above four texts reads (in order) 1. '_to God and Father_' 2. '_of God and of Father_' 3. '_of God and Father our_' 4. '_to the God and Father of the Lord of us Jesus Christ_' . Particularly, there is no Greek article before 'Father' in any of the four texts.

Comment: @NigelJ God and  the Father, means two different entities. Since there's no definite article before πατρι in the Greek text, so I think it should be "the god and father" not "God and the Father". I hope you understand me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me begin by listing all four verses you quote with my very (overly?) literal translation:

- Col 1:3, Εὐχαριστοῦμεν τῷ Θεῷ Πατρὶ τοῦ Κυρίου ἡμῶν Ἰησοῦ Χριστοῦ πάντοτε περὶ ὑμῶν προσευχόμενοι, = We give thanks to the God, Father of our Lord Jesus Christ, always praying for you,
- Col 2:2, … εἰς ἐπίγνωσιν τοῦ μυστηρίου τοῦ θεοῦ, Χριστοῦ, = in a knowledge of the mystery of God, [namely] of Christ,
- Col 3:17, … πάντα ἐν ὀνόματι κυρίου Ἰησοῦ, εὐχαριστοῦντες τῷ θεῷ πατρὶ δι' αὐτοῦ. = all in the name of Lord Jesus, giving thanks to God Father through Him.
- Gal 1:4, κατὰ τὸ θέλημα τοῦ θεοῦ καὶ πατρὸς ἡμῶν, = according to the will of God and Father of us.

There are several things about these we should note.  First, none are particularly challenging either theologically or linguistically.  Second, "Father" does not ever have an article (= "the").  This is mostly the case throughout the NT.

The theological truths taught in these verses are:

- God the Father has this title because He is called the father of Jesus Christ
- Jesus is the mystery of God
- We should give thanks to God through Jesus
- God's salvation is according to the will of God our Father
- God the Father is also called our Father

Not one of these is controversial.  Most of the differences occur because the English translation adds "the" and "and" that often do not exist in the original Greek, but are added to smooth out the English.

Answer (score 0):

{Jesus is the son of God because he came from God but he is verily God in flesh.} emphasis mine in parenthesis!! And without controversy great is the mystery of godliness: God was manifest in the flesh, justified in the Spirit, seen of angels, preached unto the Gentiles, believed on in the world, received up into glory. 1 Timothy 3:16